# JavaScript PointerEvent - "pointerover" / "pointerout" triggering in Firefox / Chrome / Edge

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

In the code below, I expect the `<div>` background-color should be changed from red to green, when a mouse or a touch pointer moving over the element.

Just tested with 3 major browsers of the latest versions with the following scenarios:

1. **Mouse**: *Hover* from the area nearby, then hover over and out of the `<div>`
2. **Mouse**: Press on the area nearby, then *drag* over and out of the `<div>`
3. **Touch**: Press on the area nearby, then *drag* over and out of the `<div>`
4. **Stylus**: *Hover* from the area nearby, then hover over and out of the `<div>`
5. **Stylus**: Press from the area nearby, then *drag* over and out of the `<div>`

**Results on Windows 10:**

- **Firefox 71** passes all the cases.
- **Edge 18** and **Chrome 79** fails for Cases #3 and #5.

Can Cases #3 & #5 performs the expected behavior when implementing PointerEvent correctly? Thanks.

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("pointerover", (e) => e.target.classList.add("pointerOver"), false);
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("pointerout", (e) => e.target.classList.remove("pointerOver"), false);
```

```css
body {
      touch-action: none;
}
#test {
      width: 10em; height: 10em;
      background-color: red;
}
#test.pointerOver {
      background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PointerEvent Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="test"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: What device did you test on? Did you test on a touch-pad with Windows 10? What is the behavior when the test failed? Is there any error in console when the test failed?

Comment: A Windows 10 laptop with a touch screen.

Comment: No error is logged in the console

Comment: We've tested with Surface pro and reproduced the behavior. This is due to the different designs of different browsers. Edge, Chrome and Firefox have different kernels, so it is normal they have a little different behavior. We can't expect them to behave totally the same.